# How can I use Visual Studio 2010 with the Visual C++ 2008 compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

I want to use Visual Studio 2010 with the 9.0 compiler, how can I do this?

I need this so I can use DarkGDK, however I do not want to switch the IDE.

Answer (score 9):

It's right there in your project properties, "Platform Toolset" defaults to "v100".

Just change that to "v90" and you are done.

Comment: Note that you need an installed copy of VS2008 to do that. A free "Visual C++ 2008 express edition" will perfectly do.

Comment: It should also work with an installed Windows SDK. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881173/using-a-v90-platform-toolset-on-visualstudio-2010 for more information regarding this topic.