# How to tell which compiler was used for a C++ static library file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I have a C++ project which I'm trying to compile, and it references functions which are defined in a pre-compiled library file.

When I try to build my project I get the error:

`LINK : fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'offending_library.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries`

The error message is clear enough, but I don't have the sources for the old objects so need to look at using the old compiler instead. I have researched other questions showing how I can install older toolsets, e.g.:

[How to select an older compiler in Microsoft Visual C++ 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904811/how-to-select-an-older-compiler-in-microsoft-visual-c-2019)

[Using a v90 Platform toolset on VisualStudio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881173/using-a-v90-platform-toolset-on-visualstudio-2010)

It seems that sometimes this can be done without installing the relevant version of Visual Studio (which I'd prefer as apparently advice is to remove any existing installs and re-install them in chronological order).

However, first I need to know **which** "older compiler" was used. Is there a way to determine that?

Comment: I think your bigger concern should be the lack of sources.

Comment: Out of  curiosity, is this a static library or an import library? The former (at least) is [talked about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411854/is-there-a-way-to-determine-which-version-of-visual-studio-was-used-to-compile-a).

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4554510/10553341

Comment: @WhozCraig: It is a static library and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920599/4988601) answer at the question you linked to worked very nicely. Have upvoted there. Will mark my question as duplicate.