# How to correctly install platform toolsets

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compatibility

I know there are tons of other threads about it, but I couldn't find any which could help me.

So I've got VS2013 Ultimate installed. I've got an old project which works with only VS2008SP1. On other compilers it has compatibility issues which I don't want to bother with. So I would like to try to compile it from 2013 with 2008 tools, so I hope I can compile it without uninstalling my current VS2013.

- So, if I install VS2008, will this overwrite my current 2013 or just getting added as a toolset?
- If I use 2008 toolset, will this work the same way as I had a VS2008?
- Do I have to do something else to make it work?

And just a secondary question which is not related to may current question at all:
If I compile a lib with VS2013, can I use this lib in my VS2008 Project, or do I have to compile the lib with VS2008 too?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't recommend installing VS 2008 if you already have VS 2013 installed. In general they say:

> We recommend that you install Visual Studio versions in the order in
>   which they were released. For example, install Visual Studio 2012
>   before you install Visual Studio 2013.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx

So, to answer your question: you probably should uninstall VS 2013, but you can install it again after installing VS 2008. Before doing that though it might be a good idea to clean the register as well as file leftovers from VS 2013 to avoid compatibility problems.

And yes, you can use 2008 compiler in 2013 version. There are a plenty of SO thread about it, e.g. :

[Use Visual Studio 2012 and compile with older platform toolset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453629/use-visual-studio-2012-and-compile-with-older-platform-toolset)

[How can I use Visual Studio 2010 with the Visual C++ 2008 compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621621/how-can-i-use-visual-studio-2010-with-the-visual-c-2008-compiler)

> If I compile a lib with VS2013, can I use this lib in my VS2008
>   Project, or do I have to compile the lib with VS2008 too?

You have to compile this lib in VS 2008, if you want to use it with VS 2008.

Comment: So you say, that I should uninstall VS2013, then install 2008 and install 2013 too? This way I will have the ability to chose 2008 as a compiler at platform choosing. Right?

So if I compile that lib with 2008 toolset, I'll be able to use it with my 2008 project, right?

Thank you!